# Is scipy.linprog with method='interior-point' suitable for non linear optimization with large data set? if not then what's the alternative?

Tags: python, optimization

I'm doing non linear optimization using python. I have a large data set,around 100,000 rows.
My objective function is like

```
z=(aXLM+bXNM-c)XCM, where a,b & c are constant.LM & NM are the variables which I need to modify to maximize z
```

CM is defined as

```
CM=exp(k+m*log(LM)+n*log(NM))+K1 where K, K1, m & n are constant & CM will come in equality constraint CM=S
```

I was using interior point method because I have a large data set of 100,000 records & initially my model was linear. Given the non linear model & such a big data set can you please suggest me if method='interior-point' suitable or not? & If not suitable then considering the large data set which optimization technique I should use in python?

Comment: How were you even using `linprog` at all? `linprog` is linear programming, and your objective is nonlinear.

Comment: @user2357112, as I mentioned in my first post, Initially my problem was linear, so I was using linprog. Can you please suggest me which non linear technique is suitable for handling around 100,000 rows of data set in python?

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Your model is not very clearly stated, so I don't understand it. Large scale nonlinear programming solvers are readily available (to mention a few: ipopt, minos, snopt, conopt, knitro). Many can be accessed through the Pyomo Python modeling tool.